# Should I wash newly bought plastic tumblers?

Tags: cleaning, dishwasher

Just [bought these cups from IKEA](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10192956/).

[image]

Beside from being dusty, I asked myself whether I should put these once before usage into the dishwasher to "wash away toxics" that might be on the surface of the cups.

On the other hand, this might be pure superstition.

**My question:**

Should I dishwash plastic cups/plates before first use?

Comment: Care to tell me why the downvote?

Comment: Why would you NOT want to wash something before using it to consume a beverage?

Comment: @coscallis maybe because it came wrapped and/or looks clean and/or is likely to be covered with something that is not cleanable by simply washing with water and soap?

Comment: I think washing by hand with warm water and soap should be fine. A dishwasher isn't necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, yes, to wash off any chemicals that might have been used to finish the plastics or rinse any sprue away. If you're going to be putting the dishwasher on anyway, you might as well throw them in.

Comment: And if the products were not packaged, wash off whatever ended up on the product after who-knows-how-many other people in the store handled it before you bought it. When you've seen someone in a store pick their nose then pick up some kitchen appliance and then put it down, you'll know what I mean. ;)

Comment: What chemicals might these be? Least time I checked food grade injection molding didn't use spurious chemicals. Only virgin resin and heat

Comment: @TFD, most likely, a release agent used to coat the injection mold.

Comment: Release agents aren't normally used for plastic injection molding? They are used for fiberglass etc.

Answer (score 1):

Lemon and or pine oil (lemon first) could be helpful along with baking soda mixed in, shake it around or use as a warm washing mix. Alternatively you can use soap and warm water, just be sure it smells like clean plastic when you're done, not chemicals from production or from your soap.